# Как выдать права в группе вк через python?

Tags: вконтакте

Тупа ничего не происходит

```
import vk_api
import random
import time

token = "token"


vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)

vk._auth_token()


while True:
    try:
        messages = vk.method("messages.getConversations", {"offset": 0, "count": 20, "filter": "unanswered"})
        if messages["count"] >= 1:
            id = messages["items"][0]["last_message"]["from_id"]
            body = messages["items"][0]["last_message"]["text"]
            if body.lower() == "привет":
                vk.method("group.editManager",{"group_id": 187698788}, {"user_id": 548834958}, {"role": moderator})
                vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "готово", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
except Exception as E:
        time.sleep(1)
```